# Reverse words in a text

Tags: c

I am attempting to reverse words in a text, so for example:

```
I love you.
You love me.
We're a happy family.
```

Should be:

```
I evol .uoy
uoY evol .em
er'eW a yppah .ylimaf
```

My approach was to open, then read the file, afterwards, create an array with X size, and whenever we have an empty string in the text, we skip this. Otherwise, create an array to allocate a smaller size to the first array, this size should be equal to the number of elements in the array. Then update the first array by this array (to share the same memory allocation.) Lastly, we increment `j` relative to `inc_reset`, when `inc_reset > 1`, and `inc_reset` will reset after each time its greater than 1. Then inside the while loop, we reverse the first index value with the next. This should always update for `inc_reset = 2`, and we increment `j = 1`, so we always reverse the first two values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_READ 50
int main(){
    int fd;
    fd = open("files/text_1.txt", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[MAX_READ+1];
    ssize_t numRead;

    numRead = read(fd, buffer, MAX_READ);
    if (numRead == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    buffer[numRead] = '\0';
    char temp_buffer[MAX_READ] = {'\0'}; 
    char* var = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    char store_i[MAX_READ] = {0};
    int j = 0;
    size_t inc;
    int inc_reset;
    for(int i = 0; i < numRead; i++){
        if (buffer[i] == ' '){
            continue;
        } else {
            store_i[i] = i;
            inc += i;
            inc_reset += i;
            char* var_reset = realloc(var, inc);
            var_reset[i] = buffer[i];
            
            if(inc_reset > 1){
                *var = *var_reset;
                while(j < inc_reset){
                    
                    var[j] = var[j+1];
                    j++;
                }
                inc_reset = 0;
                j = 0;
            }}}

    for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(store_i)/sizeof(store_i[0]); k++){
        //printf("\n%c", var[store_i[k]]);
        buffer[store_i[k]] = var[store_i[k]];
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1){
        printf("Closing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: start with a function that reverses the letters of a word, do you have that? Then you just need to [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html) each line based on a space, then send each word to your function. There's a lot going on in `main` here, and `realloc` seems overly aggressive. Start with something simpler.

Comment: `strtok()` consumes delimiters so I  suggest `strpbrk()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems overly complicated.

If you can assume a fixed length of a line, `LEN`, then I suggest you use `fgets()` to read a line.  Then you process the line by using `strpbrk()` to find your delimiter, `reverse()` it, then `strchr()` to find a non-delimiter and print your delimiters out.  This is robust in case you have multiple consecutive delimiters.  The code below reads input from stdin so you would call it `./a.out < files/text_t.txt`.  Or you can modify the code to read that fixed file.

If you don't want to assume a fixed line length you can dynamically allocate `s` then resize it as needed (if !feof() and last byte of `s` isn't `\n`) then append another chunk.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 1024
#define SEP " \n"

void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

char *reverse(char *begin, char *end) {
    char *s = begin;
    for(end--; begin < end; begin++, end--) {
        swap(begin, end);
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char s[LEN];
    while(fgets(s, LEN, stdin)) {
        char *begin = s;
        while(*begin) {
            char *end = strpbrk(begin, SEP);
            if(!end) break;
            printf("%.*s", (int) (end - begin), reverse(begin, end));
            begin = end;
            while(strchr(SEP, *end)) end++;
            printf("%.*s", (int) (end - begin), begin);
            begin = end;
        }
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
cat <<EOF | ./a.out
I love you.
You love me.
We're a happy family.
EOF
I evol .uoy
uoY evol .em
er'eW a yppah .ylimaf
```

Another approach is to `mmap()` the input file (using MAP_PRIVATE flag), then use a similar algorithm below like the inner `while()` loop.  You can defer printing till the end if you prefer.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach! I will have to study over it, however, I cannot wrap my head around you `for-loop` for `reverse`, can you explain the conditions, i..e why `end--` is first and `begin++, end--` is last, I have not seen a loop like this before. I was going to attempt a version with linked lists, and given your version, I'll make multiple approaches. Thank you!

Comment: @Emil11 Let's say the word is `love` when we call `reverse()` `begin` points to `l and `end` points to the position after `e`.  So we back it up one so it points to `e`.  Then we swap the two.  Now we increment `begin` so it now points to `o` and decrement `end` so it now points to `v`.  Alternatively, you can pass in length of the word `size_t n = end - begin` then use a regular `for()` loop: for(size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) swap(begin + i, begin + n - 1 - i);`

Comment: @Emil11 Modify the code with some print statements to see what it does in each loop iteration.   Or even better invest a couple of hours into using a debugger like gdb.  It's very much worth your time.  `gdb ./a.out` then `b reverse`, `r`, now use `p begin`, `n` to take the next step.